# How to download unknown object from S3 using Python Boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to write a Python app that when it polls my SQS queue and receives a message that a new object has been added to the s3 bucket, it will go into there and download it.

I'm seeing the issue here as in the docs, the method to download from s3 is stated as this:

```
s3.download_file('BUCKET_NAME', 'OBJECT_NAME', 'FILE_NAME')
```

The issue here is that obviously I DO know the object name that I want to download (eg. fileOne.csv), but theoretically I shouldn't, as the Python app will  poll the SQS queue and download whatever the file is that triggered this message to be sent to the SQS queue. As well as this, I'm of course going to add more files at different times,with many different names, so how can I get my script to download the certain file/object that has caused the certain SQS message?

Comment: Doesn't the message sent to your SQS queue contain this information?

Comment: @larsks I've had a look through the message and cant seem to find the name anywhere, it's all just metadata

Comment: Does it look like [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html)?

Comment: @larsks Yes it does, I see in the "object" section it contains the name of the file as the "key" do I need to write some sort of a script that can take in all the json and just pull out that key?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html), the message you receive via SQS contains information about the newly added file in the `s3` section of each event record:

```
[...]
         "s3":{  
            "s3SchemaVersion":"1.0",
            "configurationId":"ID found in the bucket notification configuration",
            "bucket":{  
               "name":"bucket-name",
               "ownerIdentity":{  
                  "principalId":"Amazon-customer-ID-of-the-bucket-owner"
               },
               "arn":"bucket-ARN"
            },
            "object":{  
               "key":"object-key",
               "size":object-size,
               "eTag":"object eTag",
               "versionId":"object version if bucket is versioning-enabled, otherwise null",
               "sequencer": "a string representation of a hexadecimal value used to determine event sequence, 
                   only used with PUTs and DELETEs"
            }
         },
[...]
```

You can extract both the bucket name and object name from this information.

---

If you'd like some sort of example showing how to get the information you want out of the event record, please update your question to show the code you're using to receive the messages from your SQS queue.

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like:

```py
for object in event['Records']:
    bucket = object['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = object['s3']['object']['key']

    ## Do something here with bucket and key
```